# Django save long running process on completion

Tags: python, django

I want to create an application that interacts with external APIs which create and manage a long running process (can be minutes/hours). Django app would save a model instance only when the process is successful.

On form submission, external API is triggered to run a process with parameters from form submission. External API gives job uuid, what's the preferred way of checking the status? Should it be checked in Model save() in a while loop (via job status GET requests to external API)? Or is there a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
My answer assumes you've already integrated an asynchronous processing library such as celery.

One solution would be to create a model to track these tasks. Then create a task `chain` such that when your external API task finishes, it feeds into another task that marks the tracker as complete. This may not be exactly what you need, but it provides a general idea of what you can do.

Model:

```
class FormSubmissionTracker(models.Model):
    created = ...
    updated = ...
    user = ... # Maybe?
    completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Task:

```
@shared_task # Or however you define your tasks.
def complete_tracker(tracker_id):
    FormSubmissionTracker.objects.filter(
        completed__isnull=True,
        id=tracker_id,
    ).update(completed=timezone.now())
```

View:

```
def view(request):
    form = Form()
    if form.is_valid():
        tracker = FormSubmissionTracker.objects.create(user=request.user)
        task = YourExternalTask.si() # This maybe should be .s() depending on your use case
        (task | complete_tracker.si(tracker.id)).apply_async()
```

Comment: You should have noted that your approach needs additional software. I think what you are talking about is using ``celery`` ?

Comment: You're right that was my assumption. I should have made that clear.